# StringIndexer NumberFormatException for value not visible in column

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark

Here are all of the distinct values in the column I'm trying to encode. `state_msg` is `string`.

```
df.groupBy('state_msg').count().show()
+----------+--------+                                                           
| state_msg|   count|
+----------+--------+
|Redirected|      28|
|      Busy|  164790|
|  Canceled| 1063663|
|  Finished|36100201|
|Terminated|   12982|
|    Failed|  941183|
| Timed out| 5726363|
|     Error| 1957993|
|  Off-line|  186322|
| Not found|  592259|
+----------+--------+
```

I am attempting to one-hot-encode this column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='state_msg', outputCol='state_msg_index')
indexed_df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

But I receive this exception, which makes no sense, since `"1234567890"` is not a possible value in `state_msg`, according to the distinct values produced by that groupBy above.

```
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1234567890"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

---

```
df.groupBy('state_msg').count().show(n=100)
+----------+--------+
| state_msg|   count|
+----------+--------+
|Redirected|      28|
|      Busy|  165241|
|  Canceled| 1067515|
|  Finished|36270559|
|Terminated|   12997|
|    Failed|  944131|
| Timed out| 5745550|
|     Error| 1959041|
|  Off-line|  186899|
| Not found|  593823|
+----------+--------+

df.agg(countDistinct('state_msg').alias('count')).show()

+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|   10|
+-----+
```

Comment: @pault, attached output from both runs above

Comment: I wonder if it could be from a different field. It doesn't match at all the string values in `state_msg`, obviously, and there are other columns with similar 10-digit values. There is the possibility that the directory I'm globbing from has some CSVs with 15 columns while others have the same 15 plus 2 at the end. I wonder if this could be an issue, but my testing whether it would be has been inconclusive...

Comment: I made a simple example, globbing two files, one with `a,b,c` columns, the other with `a,b,c,d,e`, and Spark by default just truncate `d,e`, leaving an *n*x3 DataFrame.

Comment: It certainly doesn't seem like you should get that error based on those value counts

Comment: I agree with @pault !